# I have to buy ('Je dois acheter' or ...)

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I'm wondering if both of these are correct ways of saying 'I have to', and if so, whether there's any difference in what is implied:

> Je dois acheter (un parapluie) **VS** J'ai acheter (un parapluie)

Thanks.

Comment: J'ai achet**é**

Comment: @Toto Thanks. Isn’t that “I bought “? Just looking at the responses below.

Comment: Le temps de conjugaison ici est le [passé composé](http://www.conjugaison-verbe.fr/conjugaison/verbe/acheter.htm), l’auxiliaire avoir + le participe passé.

Comment: Merci. Je comprends un peu. I will come back to this though, as I’ve only just started learning French :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is correct but the second one is not grammatical and would also be confused with *j'ai acheté un parapluie* (I bought an umbrella) in spoken French.

You might say:

> *J'ai à acheter un parapluie*. (very rare, might be perceived as an anglicism)
>
> *Je n'ai pas à acheter un/de parapluie*. (common)
>
> *J'ai un parapluie à acheter*.

Answer (score 2):

As @jlliagre said the second sentence is not correct.

If you want to say "I have to" you can also say

> Il **faut que** j'achète un parapluie

Comment: And another way to put it: *Il me faut acheter un parapluie*.

Comment: Il me faut acheter un parapluie.. au 19e siecle :-)